# Conditional Expectation Counterexample

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

I am trying to think of a counterexample to the following:

If $E(Y|X) =0$, and $E(Y^2|X) = \sigma ^2$, a constant, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: $$Y=\varepsilon\sqrt{1+\eta g(X)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=1/2$.  Conditional on  $X=0$ let $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and conditional on $X=1$ let $Y\sim U[-6,6]$.  For example.